# jQuery UI Autocomplete mouse click selection not passing value

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in a PHP page for location services. This one in particular is using the Remote JSONP datasource type. The issue I have is odd, and only happening with one way.

Here is what is happening:

1. The user types out the entire selection. The value is assigned and passed as expected.
2. The user types out part of the selection and uses the keyboard to drop down to the selection wanted and presses the enter key. The value is assigned and passed as expected.
3. The user types out part of the selection and clicks on the selection wanted. Only the segment that was typed up to the point in which they clicked is passed.

In other words, if the user types out `Location`, then `Location` is passed. If the user types out `Loca` and uses the keyboard to drop down to `Location`, then `Location` is passed. However, if the user types `Loca` and uses the mouse to click on `Location`, `Loca` is passed.

This is inside of a plugin, so I will explain the best I can and show relative code. When I say it is being passed, it is being passed in the PHP variable `$thisVAR`.

I just can't figure out why the value is passed as the typed segment rather than the full value assigned.

Here is the PHP creating the js when the field is being created:

```
$js .= "$( function(){";
$js .= "$('.error').hide();";
$js .= "var rollbackValue = '';";
$js .= "$('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').keyup(function(){";
$js .= "rollbackValue = $(this).val().slice(0,-1);";
$js .= "});";
$js .= "$('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').autocomplete({";
$js .= "source: function( request, response ){";
$js .= "$.ajax({";
$js .= "url: '" . $thisURL . "',";
$js .= "dataType: 'jsonp',";
$js .= "data: {";
$js .= "term: request.term,";
$js .= "dependents: '". $thisVAR . "',";
$js .= "field: '". $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "',";
$js .= "fieldSettings: " . json_encode($fieldSettings);
$js .= "},";
$js .= "success: function( data ) {";
if( $fieldSettings['allow_other_countries'] == 'n' ){
    $js .= "if (!data || !Object.keys(data).length){";
    $js .= "$('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').prev('.error')";
    if( !empty($fieldSettings['custom_error']) ){
        $js .= ".html('" . $customError . "')";
    }else{
        $js .= ".html('Sorry, there were no available records found starting with `<span style=\"text-transform: capitalize;\">' + request.term + '</span>`.')";
    }
    $js .= ".fadeIn('slow', function(){ $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut('slow'); });";
    $js .= "$('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').val(rollbackValue);";
    $js .= "} else {";
    $js .= "    response( data );";
    $js .= "}";
}else{
    $js .= "response( data );";
}
$js .= "},";
$js .= "minLength: 0";
$js .= "});";
$js .= "}";
$js .= "});";
$js .= "});";
```

That equates to the following in js (Easier to read):

```
$( function(){
    $('.error').hide();
    var rollbackValue = '';
    $('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').keyup(function(){
        rollbackValue = $(this).val().slice(0,-1);
    });
    $('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ){
            $.ajax({
                url: '" . $thisURL . "',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    dependents: '". $thisVAR . "',
                    field: '". $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "',
                    fieldSettings: " . json_encode($fieldSettings);
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    if ( !data || !Object.keys(data).length ){
                        $('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').prev('.error')
                        .html('Sorry, there were no available records found starting with `<span style=\"text-transform: capitalize;\">' + request.term + '</span>`.')
                        .fadeIn('slow', function(){ $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut('slow'); });
                        $('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').val(rollbackValue);
                    } else {
                        response( data );
                    }
                },
                minLength: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The variable `$thisVAR` is determined and set right above this:

```
/**
 * Determine our variables for this field
 */
$thisVAR = ''; $abbr = '';
if( strpos($suggestiveFieldArray, 'city') !== false ) {
    /**
     * We need the state and country data
     */
    $thisVAR = "$myState|$myCountry";
    $abbr = ( $fieldSettings['abbreviations'] == 'y' ? "true" : "false" );
}elseif( strpos($suggestiveFieldArray, 'state') !== false ) {
    /**
     * We need the city and country data
     */
    $thisVAR = "$myCity|$myCountry";
    $abbr = ( $fieldSettings['abbreviations'] == 'y' ? "true" : "false" );
}elseif( strpos($suggestiveFieldArray, 'country') !== false ) {
    /**
     * We need the city and state data
     */
    $thisVAR = "$myCity|$myState";
    $abbr = ( $fieldSettings['abbreviations'] == 'y' ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

...And `$myCity`, `$myState`, and `$myCountry` are all just pulled as values from the fields' values.

```
/**
 * Associative Fields Values
 */
if($field['name'] == 'theField_city'){
    $myCity = $field['value'];
}elseif($field['name'] == 'theField_state'){
    $myState = $field['value'];
}elseif($field['name'] == 'theField_country'){
    $myCountry = $field['value'];
}
```

Comment: Thats a monumental pile of code for us to wade through... ;) Even so, it doesnt seem to be shedding light on why thats happening. Its almost like you have a second click event somewhere that is ... overriding what .autocomplete has built in.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry. I just figured it was best to throw it all up there instead of getting questions as to where 'x' is being assigned, etc.  ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat Agreed, but there is nothing.

Comment: I've seen other similar issues in which they had to use the `select` event to capture the mouse click event. I tried that as well, but saw no change in results.

Comment: Right, on one of ours I use select: to add a hidden field to the form with a specific ID I want sent in, and submit the form. Regardless what junk was left in the text input field. But the DEFAULT behavior should be to 'select and submit' the value clicked on. It says so in the docs =p Very odd issue you have going on here :(

Comment: If I use console.log to retrieve the value, it shows the entire value that is expected. However, the code passing the value to the back doesn't. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Which version of jquery are you linking in?

Comment: It's included by something else. Using `console.log(jQuery().jquery)` returned 2.1.3 though.

Comment: @BrianMallett can you provide an example of the data that is returned to the AJAX? If it works for 2/3 of the scenarios, I am wondering if maybe it's getting an odd array back.

Comment: @twisty It doesn't even get to the point of returning data because the var being passed is incomplete

Comment: @BrianMallett what doe you see in the Network inspection for your AJAX call for Parameters?

Comment: That's where I am getting the shortened variable. It shows 'Sack' when I click on 'Sackville'. If I use the keyboard to select it then it shows 'Sackville'. I verified this with echoing the received var on the backend. This is what led to the question.  ;)

Comment: Ok, so it's sending the proper value to the PHP. Since this is using itself as the backend script, is there a reason you are using JSONP instead of just JSON? Can you provide an example of the expected results for 'sack'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without example data, I could only make some guesses. To make it more fluid, I would adjust some of your `id` attributes to use `-` instead of `_`. Minor preference and something to consider.

I used the following data for testing and made some assumptions about your HTML. If you're returning an object, which I suspect you are, it must contain at least a `label` and `value` pair.

```
[{
  label: "San Jose, CA US",
  value: "San Jose",
  city: "San Jose",
  state: "California",
  stateAbbr: "CA",
  country: "United States"
}, {
  label: "Santa Clara, CA US",
  value: "Santa Clara",
  city: "Santa Clara",
  state: "California",
  stateAbbr: "CA",
  country: "United States"
}, {
  label: "Mountain View, CA US",
  value: "Mountain View",
  city: "Mountain View",
  state: "California",
  stateAbbr: "CA",
  country: "United States"
},
{
  label: "Springfield, OR US",
  value: "Springfield",
  city: "Springfield",
  state: "Oregon",
  stateAbbr: "OR",
  country: "United States"
},
{
  label: "Springfield, NY US",
  value: "Springfield",
  city: "Springfield",
  state: "New York",
  stateAbbr: "NY",
  country: "United States"
}];
```

I would also advise using POST versus GET and use JSON versus JSONP. You'd really only want to use GET if you were sending a single term or a short amount of data. POST is better for larger amounts of data and marginally safer.

JSONP would only be helpful if you're PHP server is hosted within another domain or under another API than your Web Server. Since PHP is generating the JavaScript code and the AJAX is calling the PHP Self I can see no reason to use JSONP.

In your auto complete, you seem to want the following:

- Generate an error alert if no results are returned
- Auto populate City, State, and Country based on the users entry
- The State may or may not use an abbreviation

I am assuming that if they start typing in a City name and make a selection, it should populate the corresponding State and Country details.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5r1by1xp/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="error"></div>
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" id="fn-city" data-abbr="n" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="error"></div>
      <label>State</label>
      <input type="text" id="fn-state" data-abbr="y" style="width: 2em;" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="error"></div>
      <label>Country</label>
      <input type="text" id="fn-country" data-abbr="n" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-widget ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.ui-widget ul li label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}

.ui-widget .error {
  font-size: 65%;
  color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Only used for example & jsFiddle
var myData = [{
  label: "San Jose, CA US",
  value: "San Jose",
  city: "San Jose",
  state: "California",
  stateAbbr: "CA",
  country: "United States"
}, {
  label: "Santa Clara, CA US",
  value: "Santa Clara",
  city: "Santa Clara",
  state: "California",
  stateAbbr: "CA",
  country: "United States"
}, {
  label: "Mountain View, CA US",
  value: "Mountain View",
  city: "Mountain View",
  state: "California",
  stateAbbr: "CA",
  country: "United States"
}, {
  label: "Springfield, OR US",
  value: "Springfield",
  city: "Springfield",
  state: "Oregon",
  stateAbbr: "OR",
  country: "United States"
}, {
  label: "Springfield, NY US",
  value: "Springfield",
  city: "Springfield",
  state: "New York",
  stateAbbr: "NY",
  country: "United States"
}];

$(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  var rollbackValue = '';
  $("[id|='fn']").keyup(function() {
    rollbackValue = $(this).val().slice(0, -1);
  });
  $("[id|='fn']").focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("activeField")
  }).blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("activeField");
  }).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var fnid = $(".activeField").attr("id");
      var dep = fnid.slice(fnid.indexOf("-") + 1);
      var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify(myData),
          term: request.term,
          dependents: dep,
          field: fnid,
          fieldSettings: JSON.stringify({
            abbreviations: $("#" + fnid).data("abbr")
          })
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var results = [];
          $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            var depResult = v[dep].toLowerCase();
            if (depResult.indexOf(term) === 0) {
              results.push(v);
            }
          });
          if (results.length == 0) {
            console.log("No Results Found.");
            $("#" + fnid).parent().find(".error")
              .html('Sorry, there were no available records found starting with `<span style=\"text-transform: capitalize;\">' + term + '</span>`.')
              .fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
              });
            $("#" + fnid).val(rollbackValue)
            ''
          }
          response(results);
        },
        minLength: 0
      });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
      $("#fn-city").val(ui.item.city);
      $("#fn-state").val(ui.item.stateAbbr);
      $("#fn-country").val(ui.item.country);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

I personally would not use PHP to generate the JavaScript itself. It can be done, and if you're using templates and a lot of data is not static, you may not be able to get away from it too much. For example, you can define and store various function in a JS file; add them via `<script>` and then pass stuff to them from PHP:

**JS**

```
function makeAutoComplete(fID){
  var $field = $("#" + fID);
  $field.autocomplete();
}
```

**PHP**

```
$js = "<script src='myfunctions.js'></script>\r\n";
$js .= "<script>\r\n";
$js .= "makeAutoComplete('" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "-" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "')\r\n";
$js .= "</script>\r\n";
```

In this way you minimize the amount of cross context. It also make's it a lot easier troubleshoot and test. Also I would separate your PHP scripts. It's ok to make small PHP script that just get data posted to them and then return data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is some good information. I will go through it this morning and see what I can adapt to use. You are correct in the assumption that I cannot get away from using the PHP to create the JS for much of it being that this is in an addon format usage. One of the reasons for the heavy and cross context usage is because the fields are being created dynamically dependent upon selections during configuration. ... CONT

Comment: Also, the City, State, and Country data is coming from a separate data source which is in 3 different tables. Luckily, I can join them with the queries, but each field calls a separate method in a server-side PHP file. ;) Thank you for the thorough answer. It is much appreciated. There is some great information here.

Answer (score 0):

There is surely a better way of doing this, but I was able to achieve what I was needing by adding a separate js file with a small plugin that declared "global" variables to be modified on change events after the new data is returned from the ajax request. I guess I was just trying to do too much with a single file. :(